# Examples of BV functions $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with singular derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, soft-question, geometric-measure-theory

What are examples of two BV functions $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with singular derivative?

More precisely, I'd like to see an example of

- a function 
  $$u_1 \in BV(\mathbb R^2; \mathbb R^2)$$
  with only jump part in the derivative $$Du_1 = D^{jump} u_1$$
- and of a function with only Cantor part in the derivative:
  $$u_2 \in BV(\mathbb R^2; \mathbb R^2)$$
  with $$Du_2 = D^{cantor} u_2$$

---

A related more general question is on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328493/heuristic-and-graphic-representation-of-bv-functions-and-their-singularities).

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a one-dimensional BV functions $f$ into higher-dimensional examples by defining a radial function $u(x) = f(\|x\|)$. E.g., if $f(x)=-1$ for $x \le 1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x>1$, then $u(x) = f(\|x\|)$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ has as distributional derivative the surface measure on the unit sphere, by the divergence theorem, so it is a BV function with $Du$ consisting only of a "jump" part. Explicitly, if $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth test function with compact support, then
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \phi \cdot \nabla u= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u \,\, \textrm{div}\, \phi = \int_{\|x\|\le 1} \textrm{div}\, \phi = \int_{\|x\|=1} \phi \cdot n \, dS
$$
where the first integral is "formal" in the sense that $\nabla u$ does not exist as a function, with the precise meaning given by the second integral (using integration by parts/Green's formula over a large disk), and the last equality is the divergence theorem, with $n$ the normal vector and $dS$ the boundary measure, in this case 1-dimensional length measure on the circle. Since this is true for all test functions, we get that $\nabla u = n \, dS$ in the distributional sense.

A similar example with the Cantor staircase will give you a function whose derivative only has a singularly continuous ("Cantor") part.

Comment: This is interesting. 1. Could you please add a picture of the radial $2$-dimensional version of Cantor Staircase (with Mathematica or Matlab)? 2. Do you have any other genuinely 2-dimensional examples in mind?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that $f(\|x\|)$ satisfies Alberti rank-one theorem. What would the distributional derivative of $f(\|x\|)$ be?

Comment: @Riku: Just take a picture of the 1-dimensional Cantor staircase and rotate it about the $y$-axis... The distributional gradient of $u$ is given by the flux through the unit sphere, and it is trivially of rank one here, because the codomain is one-dimensional. (I realize you asked for an example from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but you can just compose the given $u$ with a trivial embedding of the real line into the plane, or more generally some Lipschitz embedding.)

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "The distributional gradient of u is given by the flux through the unit sphere"?

Comment: Also, the singularity appears to be on concentric circles around the origin, which does not seem "unidirectional" in the sense of Alberti rank-one theorem. What am I missing?

Comment: @Riku: I added more details about the distributional gradient. A gradient vector is always rank-one, no matter in which dimension. You could only potentially get larger rank if both the domain and codomain have dimension larger than one.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Could you add some more details on the costruction of the radial Cantor function and the computation of its derivative? I still feel like I'm missing something.